# Exact positioning of items on packed ice water conveyors?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm building a triple-Minerva villager breeder. I've got the packed ice going like so up-top.

```
████▒▒████
█▒▒█▒▒█▒▒█
█▒▒█▒▒█▒▒█
█▒▒█▒▒█▒▒█
█▒▒█▒▒█▒▒█
█▒▒█▒▒█▒▒█
█▒▒█▒▒█▒▒█
█▒▒█▒▒█▒▒█
█▒▒████▒▒█
```

Obviously, this is top-down. █/full block is packed ice, ▒/medium shade is the slabs over the villagers.

Problem is, no matter how I lay down water, the bread won't travel the full squiggle. It keeps getting dumped off to the side, trying to take off under the slabs. How do I arrange water/waterlogged whatever/gates to keep bread moving down the center of the ice chute so it gets to everyone? *Can* I do that?

In sum: how do I create a water/ice conveyor, defined by top-slabs, such that the stuff on the conveyor won't "understeer" and skate off under them?

Answer (score 2):

The arrangement you want is this one:

[image]

Explanation: The water either has to flow around the corner, meaning that it goes at least one block further after the turn, or it has to start in the corner and the previous water has to point towards it. If any water stream ends in a corner, the items will only be pushed against the wall and not swim on towards the next water stream.